# Retrieve the time of pressing signup button

Tags: php, forms, date, submit

I have a simple php form. Its saving all the data in the db perfectly. But now I want exact that date and time when a user clicks Submit button after filling the form. Currently its saving the date as 0000-00-00 in the db. 
Thanks...

Comment: `$date = date("Y-m-d");`. Using JS is useless as anyone can modify the posted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your INSERT query, in the date field use NOW()

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`date`, .., ..) VALUES(NOW(), .., ..)
```

Comment: Better use NOW() and mysql date than php date.
But of course, both solutions works.

Comment: I already have done that. It shows the current date and time. I want to display the date and time when a user clicks submit button.

Comment: So what is the problem? When the user clicks submit button, then use that on your query!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column like created_at in your db, use the mysql

```
 ON CREATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: done but still the same problem. its showing current server time not the time when user clicks the submit button